# Вывод данных из БД по алфавиту

Tags: php, сортировка, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть таблица

```
id | name | description | parent_id | type
```

Возник вопрос вот в чем. Пользователь выбирает на странице букву алфавита, допустим русский:

```
А Б В Г Д Е Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ы Э Ю Я
```

нужно, что-бы mysql отсортировала "name" именно по выбранной букве, и вывела только этот запрос. Помоги составить запрос, или посоветуйте ссылку, гуглил, но что-то ничего полезного не обнаружил=(

Заранее спасибо!

---

Спасибо, с запросом разобрался, работает.
Теперь возник вопрос в другом... не стал уж создавать новый топ, пишу в этом

Есть класс

```
class mainMenu extends mysql 
{
private $category_arr = array();
public $sort;

    public function __construct($s=NULL)
    {
        $this->sort = $s;
        if($this->sort==NULL)
        {
        $this->category_arr = $this->_getCategory();
        } 
        else 
        {
           $this->category_arr = $this->_getCategory_sort();
        }
    }

    private function _getCategory() 
    {
        $query = $this->query("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `type` = '0'");

        $return = array();
        while($arr = $this->fetch($query))
         {
            $return[$arr['parent_id']][] = $arr;
         }

        return $return;
    }
    private function _getCategory_sort()
    {
        $query=$this->query("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE LEFT(`name`,1) = '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->sort)."' ");

        $return = array();
        while($arr = $this->fetch($query))
         {
            $return[$arr['parent_id']][] = $arr;
         }

        return $return;
    }

    public function setCatalog($parent_id)
    {
        $category = array();
        if(isset($this->category_arr[$parent_id]))
         {
            foreach($this->category_arr[$parent_id] as $value)
              {
$category[] = array('name'=>$value['name'],'description'=>$value['description'],'type'=>$value['type'],'id'=>$value['id']);
              }
         }
         return $category;
    }

}
```

Как видно, передаю в __construct() выбранную букву, если буква не выбрана, то выводим все записи, если выбрана, то только то что сортируем. Но почему то $s NULL всегда...
Битый час сижу, понять не могу, что не так...

P.S За корявость кода не судить, я только учусь!
Спасибо!

Comment: __construct($s=NULL)?

Comment: ну да. объявляю как 
$a = new mainMenu($_GET['alphabet']);

// переменные не проверяю, как пример идет

Comment: В строке

    SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE LEFT(`name`,1) = '".mysql_real_escape_string($this->sort)."'

переменная видна как она и есть, ну если вызывать как

    $a = new mainMenu("А");

Чтобы полностью понять проблему мне здесь локально, необходимо воссоздать все то, что есть у вас - база, таблицы, так как **mysql_real_escape_string** требует live коннект.

Попробуйте сперва сделать запрос к базе не через PHP, чтобы понять, насколько он "рабочий". Затем попытайтесь на время убрать обрамляющую **mysql_real_escape_string**.

Comment: @void, все эти ужасы воссоздания и "лайв коннект" заменяет банальный вывод в лог одной единственной строчки :)

Comment: @klopp Ну так в дело в том как раз, что вывод в лог показывает что все ок (в данном конкретном случае). Поэтому я предположил что ошибка скорее всего вне скрипта. Вон, товарищ разобрался - его коммент ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, но попробуйте так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE LEFT(`name`,1) = 'А'
```

А вообще, я бы наверно для таких целей или же создал связанную таблицу, или поле, в котором была бы нужная буква.

Comment: Мне кажется, или будет косяк если имя окажется нулом или пустой строкой?

Comment: С чего косяк-то? Ну, вернёт LEFT "ничего" на NULL или на пустую строку, точно так же, как и на строки "BBB", "123"...

Comment: @void , все, разобрался...
url был вида /test/?alphabet=A
поэтому не выдавал всей картины. (NULL)
запустил без mod_rewrite , все заработало.

Интересно, с чем это связано :\

Comment: mod_rewrite содержимое в студию тогда

Comment: @void, RewriteRule ^area/? area.php? [L]
  вот

Comment: Ну это никак не должно влиять.. это просто substitute ? на area.php?, тем более что у вас /test/?alphabet=A а не /area/?alphabet=A

Comment: @void, Да не, /test/ то был как пример.
На самом то деле запрос шо в url идет как /area/?alphabet=A
А почему то влияет. потому что если /area.php?alphabet=A переменную видит, то как /area/?alphabet=A не видит, var_dump() - дает NULL,
эхом, тоже пусто...

Comment: @Александр Маслов, вы хотите сказать, что это и есть ваше правило? "RewriteRule ^area/$ area.php? [L]" Естественно, оно и не будет работать. Почитайте хотя бы документацию по mod_rewrite, это обычно полезно - читать документацию :) А я бы сделал так: "^area/(.*) /area.php?alphabet=$1"

Comment: Ну тогда потому что ваш в идеале должен выглядеть так
**RewriteRule ^area/?$ /area.php?alphabet=$1**

Потому что в вашем примере нигде вхождение $1 не отлавливается.

Comment: @klopp - опередил :)

Comment: все, понял. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

Или вот так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `name` LIKE 'А%'
```

Работает именно так, для чего и предназначена.

Comment: КЭП)) Курите мануалы, господа! Все придумано до вас)